# Best way to handle complicated XML files in Swift?

Tags: ios, xml, swift, nsxmlparser

I am making an iOS app to help students schedule classes, and I am getting all of the information from an online XML file. It's a fairly big file (400,000 lines), so I plan to have it download and process periodically in the background, but always have a copy saved so the app can be used offline. I have been playing around with a few options, but none of them really seem like a good solution. This is what the XML looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<unmschedule version="1.0.4" pubdate="2016-08-26-17:00:10" source="UNM">
    <semester code="201680" name="Fall 2016" index="1">
        <campus code="ABQ" name="Albuquerque/Main">
            <college code="AP" name="School of Arch. and Planning">
                <department code="ABM" name="School Architecture Planning">
                    <subject code="ARCH" name="Architecture">
                        <course number="109" title="Design Fundamentals">
                            <catalog-description>Studio/lecture introduces fundamental principles and processes of two-, three-, and four-dimensional design. Methods of perception, technique, composition, evaluation of materials and methods, critical evaluation and graphic representation are studied through both abstract and representational assignments.</catalog-description>
                            <section crn="41646" number="002" part-of-term="1" status="S">
                               v <section-title></section-title>
                                <text>Cancel/Reschedule to CRN 57664 04/20/2016.</text>
                                <instructional-method code=""></instructional-method>
                                <delivery-type code="LC">Lecture</delivery-type>
                                <enrollment max="18">0</enrollment>
                                <waitlist max="0">0</waitlist>
                                <credits>3</credits>
                                <fees>60</fees>
                                <instructors>
                                </instructors>
                                <meeting-times>
                                </meeting-times>
                            </section>
```

**Option 1:** Use nested dictionaries: I have tried this and it mostly works, but I run into problems with things like courses where they are a dictionary of sections, but also need to have a title and description. I have also tried using the Any type, but haven't been able to get it working.

**Option 2:** Structs: These don't seem to work because you can't dynamically add new variables.

**Option3:** XML: I'm thinking this is the solution, but I haven't been able to figure out how to read XML data directly into my program (for example, displaying all Fall 2016 classes, and then all English classes, and then all English 101 sections) without parsing through the entire XML file at every step.

Any help is appreciated, I have searched the internet extensively but none of the articles I've found address XML as complex as this, so I can't figure out how to adapt it to my program.

Comment: I don't quite get the issue with the option 1. Is it a memory issue or a structure one? You can define any data types you want (structs) and then store it in the hierarchy as nested as possible.

Comment: Two problems, the first is that each course has a dictionary that holds the sections, but I also need the course dictionary to hold the title and description of the course, which would involve putting values of two separate types into a single dictionary. Same thing within each course, the example doesn't show it but many classes have more than one meeting time, so I would have to store all the string data about that section (instructor, fees, credits) and another dictionary that holds the meeting times.

Comment: Sorry to hijack your post but if you don't mind me asking, which XML parser are you using? I'm working on something similar and I need to work with this 100K lines of XML data that is updated on daily basis. I'm looking for library that reads line by line instead of uploading the whole file into memory.

Comment: I just used the XMLParser that is part of Foundation in swift. I'm not sure if it loads it into memory first or parses it as it downloads, but either way 100K lines of XML won't take up very much memory.